How best to find orientation of a mirror plane
As part of a much larger 3D-symmetry-group-finding algorithm, I have this problem about searching for mirror planes:
Let's say I have a circumscribed polygon (i.e. all of its vertices are the same distance from the origin) in 2D, and I've already determined that it has k-fold rotational symmetry. I know that if it has mirror symmetry, the mirror lines will pass through the origin and either a vertex or an edge midpoint, and that one such line will pass through the region $\phi=[0,\pi/k)$. What I want is a way to find whether there exists a mirror line and if so where it is without having to check every vertex or midpoint in that region until I find one (because identifying whether the corresponding transformation of the 3D shape is a symmetry is computationally expensive, so I want to minimize those checks if I can). It feels like there should be a property of the points that lie on the mirror line that I should be able to leverage.
Thanks in advance!

Assuming you have an nk-gon, calculate the n angles between the first n+1 points, cycle them and look for a palindrome, if you don't find one, there's no mirror symmetry.
